# How to save output of php file called from commandline?

Tags: php, command-line

I have a php file which get image from DB and output it as a jpg file. It is OK if I call the file using a web broswer or using wget command.

I need to call this file from commandline using

```
php filename.php
```

command, but ouput is printed on the screen. How can I save output as jpg on the disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by simply redirecting the output to a file, like:

```
php filename.php > test.jpg
```

`>` Will override the existing file, to append you can use `>>` instead.